# Specifing a hover border color on a textfield using a custom theme with Material UI

Tags: material-ui

Having trouble finding documentation on how to change the default border color of an outlined Textfield on hover using a custom theme on Material ui.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
MuiOutlinedInput: {
      root: {
        "&:hover:not($disabled):not($focused):not($error) $notchedOutline": {
          border: "2px solid",
          borderColor: "yellow"
        }
      }
    }
```

[Reference](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/13105#issuecomment-433211794)
[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/6qqrxk8zk)

Comment: Issue is with modifying the hover effect for the Textfield item. Everything else is well-documented and straightforward to change.

Comment: My example is not exactly not what you want ?

Comment: No, in your example the outline does not change color on hover.

Comment: @user1506630 I have used `notchedOutline` to override the default color which is blue by default.
Ok, my example updates outline on focus not on hover. Right ?

Comment: if we remove outlined variant, and just use `borders` and `&:hover` css we can achieve this ? Check my example :)

Comment: Thank you so much for being so helpful :) However I am trying to achieve that effect  using themes, as specified here: https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/ , however nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Thanks for appreciation :)
It's basically same stuff, you can apply css by using overrides. 
Make a sample sandbox, and then we can solve this :)

Comment: Here's a sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/r568oy7lzo . Thankful for any pointers on how to change the :hover color :)

Comment: @user1506630 Check updated answer, found a reference.

Answer (score 5):

### MUI v5

```
MuiTextField: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
        '& fieldset': {
          borderColor: 'black',
        },
        '&:hover fieldset': {
          borderColor: 'red',
        },
        '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
          borderColor: 'yellow',
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: I think this answer should be accepted. It shows how to override TextField styles in different states. Thank you for this solution!