# change border color on hover for Material UI TextField

Tags: html, css, material-ui

I have been trying to change the hover color of Material UI's outlined `TextFeild`. It seems like it has many state like active, focus, focused:hover etc.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52916042/specifing-a-hover-border-color-on-a-textfield-using-a-custom-theme-with-material) post on which address my problem but I don't want to add `MuiThemeProvider` every time.

I am able to achieve it some extend but still I can't change color on hover when it was not focused.

https://codesandbox.io/s/kx0zx9q7jo

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your root styles became overridden at some point. Maybe its not ideal solution, but I got it working with `!important` keyword:

```
"&:hover:not($disabled):not($focused):not($error) $notchedOutline": {
  borderColor: "red !important"
}
```