# by hover on the text field how to remove the black border

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

when we want to hover on text field some black border is coming in text field ,how to resolve that one

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
const styles = styled(TextField)({
  '*.Mui-focused': {
    borderColor: 'transparent',
    outline:'none',
  }})
export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <>
      <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Standard" variant="standard"  />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specifing a hover border color on a textfield using a custom theme with Material UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52916042/specifing-a-hover-border-color-on-a-textfield-using-a-custom-theme-with-material)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this style to set new color while hovering it

```
'&:hover fieldset': {
      borderColor: 'grey',
    },
```

Comment: Had to add `!important` as well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked For me

```
 '& .MuiInput-underline:hover:before':
{
    border: 'none !important'
},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).